# RowEditing and ActionColumn issue

Tags: extjs

I'm currently experiencing an issue with the RowEditing plugin, and was not able to find anything relevant in order to help me with it.

I gave a grid using the RowEditing plugin, and was asked to add a row containing a "reset" button. The best choice seemed to be using an actionColumn.

When the row is not in edition mode, there is no problem, the actionColumn handles clicks correctly, and I can do my processing.
But, if the row is in edition mode, then the actionColumn seems to not react at all.

I've tried to use the editor option, but nothing is happening with that. I've tough of using some listeners too, but I can't find any relevant event for this issue.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I think,if you are using a row editing plugin you wont need action column having reset because you will have "Update" and "Cancel" buttons over their to match your functionality.But,if that is your requirement then you can use cell editor plugin instead.

Comment: In the case where the row was edited a first time, then a second time : the cancel button won't allow to reset the row to its initial state; this is why I need a "reset" button.

Comment: @JRZ have you tried forcing the `canceledit` event before resetting the values? So if they aren't in edit mode, you just reset, but if they are, call `cancelEdit()` and then reset the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've choosen an other way :

```
 {
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
action : 'tarifRowAction',
handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) 
{
    console.log("got click handler § ");
    me.fireEvent("clickedMAJButton", grid, rowIndex, colIndex);
},
editor: 
{
     xtype: 'button',
     handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) 
    {
        console.log("got click handler § ");
        me.fireEvent("clickedMAJButton", grid, rowIndex, colIndex);
    },
},
items: [
            {
                 icon: 'images/image16/modifier.png',
                 action : 'tarifRowAction',
                 scope: me
            }
        ]
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve your functionality using this approach instead of row editing plugin :

```
   {
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    width: 50,
    items: [{
             icon: 'edit.png', // Use a URL in the icon config
             tooltip: 'Update',
             handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                alert("Edit " + rec.get('name'));
                rec.set("name", "LISA124"); //Here you may have your logic of updating the data with new data   
               }
             },
             {
              icon: 'reset.png',
              tooltip: 'Reset',
              handler: function (grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {
                  var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);
                  alert("Reset " + rec.get('name'));
                  rec.set("name", rec.raw.name);
                }
              }
             ]
     }
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devd/PkC77/)

You can use the approach suggested by @Jeff if you wanna stick with your requirements.